# [Neo4j][Cypher Query] Filter On Node or Relationship Node Properties and Then Return All Nodes and Their Relationship Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a Neo4j DB that contains `Resource` nodes with several relationship nodes including `Tag`, `Address`, `PhoneNumber`, etc.

The schema for `Resource` is as follows:

```
Resource: {
  name: str,
  description: str,
  legal_name: str,
  organization_type: str,
}
```

The schema for `Tag` is as follows:

```
Tag: {
  tag: str,
}
```

I'm building a query that returns all `Resource` nodes along with their relationship nodes where the `Resource` node has a property that contains a specific string AND/OR related `Tag` node(s) has(ve) a property that contains the same string.

Example cases to return:

1. A `Resource` node DOES have one or more property that contains the string "school" but all related `Tag` nodes DO NOT have a `tag` property containing the string "school": the `Resource` node is returned along with all of its relationship nodes
2. A `Resource` node DOES NOT have any properties that contain the string "school" but has at least one related `Tag` node that DOES have a `tag` property containing the string "school": the `Resource` node is returned along with all of its relationship nodes
3. A `Resource` node DOES have one or more property that contains the string "school" and has at least one related `Tag` node that DOES have a `tag` property containing the string "school": the `Resource` node is returned along with all of its relationship nodes

I'm currently using the below query and it works for the most part; however, for case 2 above no other relationship nodes of the originating `Resource` node are returned in the result set.  Ideally, we would ALWAYS get all relationship nodes of the `Resource` node matching the above criteria.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
MATCH (n:Resource)-[]->(m) 
WHERE n.name CONTAINS 'school'
    OR n.description CONTAINS 'school'
    OR n.legal_name CONTAINS 'school'
    OR n.organization_type CONTAINS 'school'
    OR m.tag CONTAINS 'school'
RETURN n, collect(m);
```

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using for this?

Comment: @InverseFalcon, using version "5.13-aura"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a query like this:

```
MATCH (n:Resource)
WHERE EXISTS {
    MATCH (n)-[*0..1]->(x)
    WHERE (x:Resource OR x:Tag)
    AND any(prop IN ['name', 'description', 'legal_name', 'organization_type', 'tag'] WHERE x[prop] CONTAINS 'school')
}

WITH n, [(n)-[]->(m) | m] as resources
RETURN n, resources;
```

This uses an EXISTS {} subquery to say that you're looking for a node (that could be the same node, or could be a connected node) that is a :Resource or :Tag node that has any of the given properties with the property value contains 'school'.

For the resulting nodes that pass that filter, THEN you can match out to and collect the connected nodes (though in this case I'm using a pattern comprehension to do so, which will be more efficient).

EDIT: Fixed up the grouping of the AND and OR operators, that should ensure the any() list predicate must always be considered.

Comment: really appreciate your response!  I wound up giving this a whirl and, unfortunately, it returned every `Resource` node in the database regardless of whether or not "school" was present

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? If the resource, or its tag contained one of those properties that contained "school" that you wanted that resource node and all its relationship nodes? You had that in every case: "the Resource node is returned along with all of its relationship nodes"

Comment: Yes, but what I'm saying is that your query returns EVERY `Resource` node in the DB, all of them, regardless of whether or not "school" is present in any of the properties on the `Resource` or the `Tag`.  Ie, it's almost the equivalent of `(n:Resource)-[]->(m)`

Comment: It might be an issue with the grouping of the AND and OR operators, and put a parenthesis around the predicates dealing with the labels. Give that a try.

Comment: AWESOME, this edit seems to work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Tags` look a lot like labels. Their one property, `tag`,  could just as easily be the label identifier. With the tags as labels, the predicates can be simplified like so:

```sql
WITH ['name', 'description', 'legal', 'organization_type'] AS props
MATCH (n:Resource)-->(m) 
WHERE n:School OR any(prop IN props WHERE m[prop] CONTAINS 'school')
RETURN n, collect(m);
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, but our DB is already populated and this would require a big refactor of much more than just the DB.  Additionally, "school" is just an example of what we would want to search for.  These are specifically tags as a type.  The answer above is giving what we're looking for.  Appreciate your response!